# Borel Bivariate Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers, borel-sets

I want to prove the following statement:

$$ \beta(t,x)=C(1+t,x)= \frac {C((1+t)x)} {1-xC((1+t)x)}  $$

Where $C(x)$ is the generating function for the Catalan Numbers and $ \beta(x) $ is the Borel generating function.

I know I have to use the fact that $$ C(t,x)= \frac {C(tx)} {1-xC(tx)}$$
But unsure what other statements i need to use. 
Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What is $\beta$ exactly?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.01597.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume 
\begin{align*}
C(t,x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n C_{n,k}t^kx^n=\frac{C(tx)}{1-xC(tx)}\tag{1}\\
B_{n,k}&=\sum_{s=k}^n\binom{s}{k}C_{n,s}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^nB_{n,k}t^k}&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{s=k}^n\binom{s}{k}C_{n,s}t^k\\
> &=\sum_{s=0}^nC_{n,s}\sum_{k=0}^s\binom{s}{k}t^k\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{s=0}^nC_{n,s}(1+t)^s}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use $\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{s=k}^n a_{k,s}=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq k\leq s\leq n}} a_{k,s}=\sum_{s=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^s a_{k,s}$.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.

> We finally obtain  from (4)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathcal{B}(t,x)}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n B_{n,k}t^kx^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{s=0}^nC_{n,s}(1+t)^s  x^n\tag{$4 \leftarrow$}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{C((1+t)x)}{1-xC((1+t)x)}}\tag{$1 \leftarrow $}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.